# Aim Assistance- how can I pick which player to aim at?

Tags: game-physics

My game has the players x,y,z coordinates, as well as my players camera yaw (only yaw, no roll or pitch), and a list of enemies x,y,z coordinates as well.  I want to implement aim assistance, but I'm having trouble coming up with the algorithm.

I'm not sure how to do this at all.  Finding the nearest enemy player is easy, but what if the player wants to aim at somebody a little bit farther than the nearest enemy player and is pointing their aim very near said player? I'd have to somehow do something with the yaw difference, but I'm not exactly sure what to do

What I have so far, in pseudocode:

```
EnemyList[Enemy1, Enemy2, Enemy3, Enemy4, Enemy5];
Player;

nearestEnemy = Player.FindNearestEnemy(EnemyList);
// in degrees, the "difference" in yaw between the players current aim and the aim they'd need to target the player
yawDiff = Player.YawDiff(nearestEnemy);

if Player.InRange(nearestEnemy) {
    Player.Aim(nearestEnemy);
}
```

I need to do something with yawDiff, I think, but not sure exactly what.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So we need to decide which metrics/heuristics to employ in order to work out which player to aim at.

Unless your game platform is 2D (e.g. Space Invaders or Thing-Thing) or pseudo-3D (e.g. Doom or Wolfenstein 3D), you need to consider the elevation of your aim as well (you don't really want to jump to some invisible player above or below your view frustum).

Another such metric you can apply is the *dot product*: compute the dot product between your view / aim direction and the vector going from you to each enemy player. If this is close to 1 then you are aiming near the player, if not then not.

To decide between two players to shoot, we can calculate the percentage difference between their dot-product metrics. We can also calculate the percentage difference between their distances. Compare these two percentage differences, and for the one that is much bigger, select the player whose corresponding metric is greater.

More advanced procedures we can do to improve the realism include:

- Distance-attenuation of accuracy / firepower - this is a very important consideration in real-life so you could consider adding this as a metric.
- Projection size: player who are closer to you obviously make bigger targets. So even if the dot product metric of the closer player were smaller, when taking this into account it may be much more favourable to aim at him, due to his comparative apparent size.